# Migrating problems from jquery-1.7.1 to jquery-3.1.1

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to update my project migrating from jquery-1.7.1 to jquery-3.1.1.
I'm creating page links for pagination and this code was working perfectly until now:

```
$(".page-link").live("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var currentPage = $(this).attr("page");
        $("#CurrentPage").val(currentPage);
        articles.search();
    });
```

Now I try to update this code and I'm doing this, but it wont work:

```
$(document).on("click", ".page-link", function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        var currentPage = $(this).attr("page");
        $("#CurrentPage").val(currentPage);
        articles.search();
    });
```

Can you help me what I'm doing wrong?

Here is my whole js file:

```
var articles = {
    init: function () {
        $(document).on("click", ".page-link", function (e) {

            e.preventDefault();

            var currentPage = $(this).attr("page");
            $("#CurrentPage").val(currentPage);
            articles.search();
        });


        $(document).on("keydown", "#SearchKeyword", function (event) {
            var key = event.keyCode || event.charCode;

            if (key == 13) {
                $("#SearchKeyword").change();
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });

        $(document).on("change", "#SearchKeyword", function () {
            if ($("#CurrentPage").length) {
                $("#CurrentPage").val(1);
            }
            articles.search();
        });
    },
    search: function () {
        var url = "/Articles/PagedArticles";
        var postdata = $("#postform").serialize();

        $.post(url,
            postdata,
            function (data) {
                $("#Results").html(data);
            });
    }
};

$(function () {
    articles.init();
});
```

When I click page link I only have Hashtag added to the and of the URL like this: http://localhost:58893/Articles# , but the paging is not working

```
@model AutoParts.Domain.Models.ArticleEditResultsViewModel
@using AutoParts.Domain.Helpers;
@using AutoPartsWeb.HtmlHelpers

@{
    var isAdministrator = User.IsInRole("administrator");
}

@Html.PageLinks(Model.PagingInfo)

@if (Model.Results.Count == 0)
{
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
            No Data.
        </div>
    </div>
}
else
{
    <table id="articles" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    #
                </th>
                <th>
                    Brand
                </th>
                <th>
                    Article
                </th>
                <th>
                    Number
                </th>
                <th>
                    Brend replace
                </th>
                <th>
                    Number Replace.
                </th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model.Results)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Brand)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Article)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Number)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BrendReplace)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NumberReplace)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.ImagePath))
                        {
                            <img src="@Url.Content("~/ImageUploads/" + item.ImagePath)" width="150" />
                        }
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @if (isAdministrator)
                        {
                            <a href="/Articles/Edit/@item.Id" class="btn-lg" title="Article Info"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span></a>
                        }
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>

    </table>
}

<script type="text/javascript">


    $(document).ready(function () {

        var responsiveHelper_dt_Locations = undefined;


        var breakpointDefinition = {
            tablet: 1024,
            phone: 480
        };

        $('#articles').dataTable({

            "bFilter": false,
            "bPaginate": false,
            "bInfo": false,
            "autoWidth": true,
            "preDrawCallback": function () {
                // Initialize the responsive datatables helper once.
                if (!responsiveHelper_dt_Locations) {
                    responsiveHelper_dt_Locations = new ResponsiveDatatablesHelper($('#dt_Locations'), breakpointDefinition);
                }
            },
            "rowCallback": function (nRow) {
                responsiveHelper_dt_Locations.createExpandIcon(nRow);
            },
            "drawCallback": function (oSettings) {
                responsiveHelper_dt_Locations.respond();
            }
        });
    })

</script>
```

And this is my PagingHelper

```
public static class PagingHelper
{
    private static readonly int displayPages = 5;

    public static MvcHtmlString PageLinks(this HtmlHelper html, PagingInfo pagingInfo)
    {
        return PageLinks(html, pagingInfo, "text-right");
    }

    public static MvcHtmlString PageLinks(this HtmlHelper html, PagingInfo pagingInfo, string cssClass)
    {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

        // CurrentPage hidden field
        var currentPage = new TagBuilder("input");
        currentPage.MergeAttribute("type", "hidden");
        currentPage.MergeAttribute("id", "CurrentPage");
        currentPage.MergeAttribute("name", "CurrentPage");
        currentPage.MergeAttribute("value", pagingInfo.CurrentPage.ToString());

        result.AppendLine(currentPage.ToString());

        if(pagingInfo.TotalPages <= 1)
            return MvcHtmlString.Create(result.ToString());

        var ulInnerTextBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        //<div class="text-right">
        var div = new TagBuilder("div");
        div.AddCssClass(cssClass);

        //<ul class="pagination pagination-sm">
        var ul = new TagBuilder("ul");
        ul.AddCssClass("pagination pagination-sm");

        string link = string.Empty;
        #region first page and previous page links

        if (pagingInfo.CurrentPage != 1)
        {
            // li first page
            // <li><a href="#">&laquo;</a></li>
            link = CreateLink(@"&laquo;", 1, false);
            ulInnerTextBuilder.Append(link);

            // li previous page
            // <li><a href="#">&lsaquo;</a></li>
            link = CreateLink(@"&lsaquo;", pagingInfo.CurrentPage - 1, false);
            ulInnerTextBuilder.Append(link);
        }

        #endregion

        #region page links

        int fromPage = (pagingInfo.CurrentPage % displayPages) == 0
            ? (pagingInfo.CurrentPage / (displayPages + 1)) * displayPages
            : (pagingInfo.CurrentPage / displayPages) * displayPages;
        int toPage = Math.Min(fromPage + displayPages, pagingInfo.TotalPages);
        for (int i = fromPage + 1; i <= toPage; i++)
        {
            // li page
            // <li><a href="#">i</a></li>
            link = CreateLink(i.ToString(), i, i == pagingInfo.CurrentPage);
            ulInnerTextBuilder.Append(link);
        }

        #endregion

        #region next page and last page links

        if (pagingInfo.CurrentPage != pagingInfo.TotalPages)
        {
            // li next page
            // <li><a href="#">&rsaquo;</a></li>
            link = CreateLink(@"&rsaquo;", pagingInfo.CurrentPage + 1, false);
            ulInnerTextBuilder.Append(link);

            // li last page
            // <li><a href="#">&raquo;</a></li>
            link = CreateLink(@"&raquo;", pagingInfo.TotalPages, false);
            ulInnerTextBuilder.Append(link);
        }

        #endregion

        ul.InnerHtml = ulInnerTextBuilder.ToString();
        div.InnerHtml = ul.ToString();
        result.Append(div.ToString());

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(result.ToString());
    }

    private static string CreateLink(string text, int page, bool active)
    {
        // li page
        // <li><a href="#">i</a></li>
        var li = new TagBuilder("li");
        var a = new TagBuilder("a");
        a.MergeAttribute("href", "#");
        a.MergeAttribute("page", page.ToString());
        a.InnerHtml = text;
        if (active)
        {
            li.AddCssClass("active");
        }
        else
        {
            a.AddCssClass("page_link");
        }

        li.InnerHtml = a.ToString();

        return li.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this isolated code or are their other scripts running prior to this because a fail further up the chain would cascade down.

Comment: What is your HTML?

Comment: @mgarcia I posted my Html and Paging Helper Class, thanks

Comment: @DreamTeK I use this script only in one view, so no prior scripts running on the view. But I also have problem with upgrading all scripts

Answer (score 0):

Write functions in this way, It'll work.

```
$(".page-link").on("click", function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var currentPage = $(this).attr("page");
    $("#CurrentPage").val(currentPage);
    articles.search();
});
```

Write other functions also in this way,

```
$("id/class").on("change", function (e) {

});

$("id/class").on("focusin", function (e) {

});

$("id/class").on("focusout", function (e) {

});

$("id/class").on("keyup", function (e) {

});
```

and so on

Comment: While I agree with this, I do not believe it will solve his issue as the code he posted is still valid for 3.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

I Don't know why this matter if someone can explain, but when I changed quotes " to ' apostrophe on click event it start working???

```
$(document).on('click', ".page-link", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var currentPage = $(this).attr("page");
            $("#CurrentPage").val(currentPage);
            articles.search();
        });
```